# How to parse out all unique variables with a certain naming convention?

Tags: c#

I have a code file and I need to find all unique objects of type `TADODataSet`, but they aren't defined in this 30,000 line file I have.

I wrote a console application that splits each line into individual words and adds that word to a list if it contains `ADODataSet` (the naming convention prefix for the objects I'm interested in) but this didn't work quite right because of how I'm splitting my lines of code.

This is all of my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"C:\somePath\Form1.cs";
        string output = @"C:\someOtherPath\New Text Document.txt";
        List<string> datasets = new List<string>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(' ');

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (word.ToLower().Contains("adodataset"))
                    datasets.Add(word);
            }
        }

        if (datasets.Count > 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(output))
            {   
                foreach (string dataset in datasets.Distinct())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(dataset);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Wrote {0} data sets to {1}", datasets.Distinct().Count(), output));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

But this didn't work as I hoped, and added "words" such as these:

```
SQLText(ADODataSetEnrollment->FieldByName("Age1")->AsString)
SQLText(ADODataSetEnrollment->FieldByName("Age2")->AsString)
SQLText(ADODataSetEnrollment->FieldByName("Age3")->AsString)
```

I'm only interested in `ADODataSetEnrollment`, so I should only have 1 entry for that variable in my output file but because that line of code doesn't contain a space it's treated as a single "word".

How can I split my `lines` array instead, so that way I can find unique variables?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RegEx matching? With RegEx you can for example say 
`RegEx.IsMatch(word, "(?i)(?<!\w)adodataset(?!\w)")`

```
> (?i) means ignore case (like uppercase, lower case, i think) 
> (?<!\w)means not preceded by a literal (like letters, ABC..., abc... and so
> forth) 
> (?!\w) means not followed by a literal RegEx.IsMatch(...)
> returns a bool value
```

Comment: I started with a regex route but I'm really bad at them. Additionally, I wasn't sure how to parse out just the value I'm looking for rather than the entire line after making sure it contained a valid data set; the same problem I'm having with my current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this as a solution:

```
string file = @"C:\somePath\Form1.cs";
string output = @"C:\someOtherPath\New Text Document.txt";
List<string> datasets = new List<string>();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
decimal i = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word.ToLower().Contains("adodataset"))
        {
            int start = word.ToLower().IndexOf("adodataset");
            string dsWord = String.Empty;
            string temp = word.Substring(start, word.Length - start);

            foreach (char c in temp)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                    dsWord += c;
                else
                    break;
            }

            if (dsWord != String.Empty)
                datasets.Add(dsWord);
        }
    }

    i++;
    Console.Write("\r{0}%      ", Math.Round(i / lines.Count() * 100, 2));
}

if (datasets.Count > 0)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(output))
    {   
        foreach (string dataset in datasets.Distinct())
            sw.WriteLine(dataset);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Wrote {0} data sets to {1}", datasets.Distinct().Count(), output));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Pretty ghetto, but it did what I needed it to do. I'll happily accept someone else's answer though if they know of a better way to use Regex to just pull out the variable name from within the line of code, rather than the whole line itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(@"text.txt");
string output = @"C:\someOtherPath\New Text Document.txt";
List<string> datasets = new List<string>();
var a = Regex.Matches(file, @"\W(ADODataSet\w*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in a)
{
    datasets.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```